# The New Username Is Not Updated In The Command-line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I changed my username and I expected it will also be updated/changed in the command line but it is not.

It is still **User**. (check picture) So, how can I change it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CASjJ.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 will break if you change the username, which is why you change your displayname instead.

It is possible to change the username and correct all the problems thereafter, but it is a far easier way to create a new user with the right username, and migrate your data from your old user to the new user by using [Profile Wizard](https://www.forensit.com/downloads.html), and then delete your old account.

You can also manually copy over all your files if you don't mind changing settings you have set in the past again, such as your desktop image, mouse cursor, mouse settings, install printers, and other settings that you've changed. If you are a poweruser, there are probably a lot of settings you have changed, but then again, you probably also know how to set them up again.

That said, if you really want to rename your username, keep in mind that you will have to create another admin user anyway, because, besides all the registry tweaks you have to perform, you also have to rename your profile folder or your profile will not load and you end up with a temporary profile. Given that you currently have your userprofile folder in use, you cannot rename the folder when you are logged into that user itself.

Comment: LPChip is not wrong.  What you need to ask yourself is "what for?".. does it really matter that your folder is named "user" ?..